# I want the code to output the years of each Deprication from year 1 to 5 ,at the moment it only displays 1 for all 5 values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

The code below displays "1" for each year and should be "1" to "5"

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Dim cost As Double
        Dim life As Double = CDbl(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim salvage As Double
        Dim numberperiod As Integer
        Dim period As Integer
        Dim depreciation1 As Double
        Dim depreciation2 As Double
        Dim isconverted1 As Boolean
        Dim isconverted2 As Boolean
        Dim isconverted3 As Boolean
        Dim year As Integer = 0

        isconverted1 = Double.TryParse(textbox1.Text, cost)
        isconverted2 = Double.TryParse(textbox2.Text, salvage)
        isconverted3 = Integer.TryParse(ListBox1.SelectedItem, period)

        lstDCB.Items.Add("Year        Depreciation")
        lstSOTY.Items.Add("Year        Depreciation")

        year = Val(year) + 1

        For numberperiod = 1 To period Step 1
            depreciation1 = Financial.DDB(cost, salvage, life, numberperiod)
            depreciation2 = Financial.SYD(cost, salvage, life, numberperiod)

            lstDCB.Items.Add(year & "              " & Math.Round(depreciation1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
            lstSOTY.Items.Add(year & "              " & Math.Round(depreciation2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))

        Next numberperiod

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

It should display 1 to 5 under year of both DDB and SYD.

Comment: Well, you assigned 1 to the year value, and then doesn't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code you posted, you never update the variable `year` in the routine after it is initialized as Zero and then updated with the statement `year = Val(year) + 1`.

I believe you meant to put that statement inside the loop body (after the calculation) so that it is incremented in each iteration of the loop.

Something like this:

```
Module VBModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim cost As Double = 100
        Dim life As Double = 12
        Dim salvage As Double = 3
        Dim numberperiod As Integer
        Dim period As Integer = 3
        Dim depreciation1 As Double
        Dim depreciation2 As Double
        Dim year As Integer = 0

        For numberperiod = 1 To period Step 1
            depreciation1 = Financial.DDB(cost, salvage, life, numberperiod)
            depreciation2 = Financial.SYD(cost, salvage, life, numberperiod)

            Console.WriteLine(year & " " & Math.Round(depreciation1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
            Console.WriteLine(year & " " & Math.Round(depreciation2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))

            year += 1
        Next numberperiod
    End Sub

End Module
```